# Showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}c=c$ using the definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} c =c$$

From the definition of limit, we want to prove that $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N>0$ such that $\forall x>N \implies |f(x)−L|<\varepsilon$; in this particular case, $|c−c|<\varepsilon$.

Proof. Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists $N=\varepsilon$ such that...

I'm stuck, as I don't know how to link $c$ with $x>N$ in the subsequent steps.

Does someone have a clue?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  There certainly exists $N>0$. In fact, $N$ could be any positive number -- see my answer

Comment: Why did you say $N=\epsilon$?  Often $N$ depends on $\epsilon$, but in this situation it need not

Comment: Are you talking about a sequence where $x_n=c$?

Comment: No, just a real c. I thought that I had to set a value for N, like N= 1 or N=ϵ.

Comment: You could take $N=1$ if you like -- that would work -- or $N$ to be any positive number, as in my answer

Comment: You're right. I was doing it like that but it didn't make sense to me at the first reading. Now it does, thanks!

Comment: The idea is that you have to show $f(x)$ is eventually within $\epsilon$ of $L$.  In this case, $f(x)$ is exactly $L$ from the get-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.  Then for any $N>0$, for all $x>N$, $|f(x)-L|=|c-c|=0<\epsilon.$